# Só exibe um registro em php

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma lista mostrando os registros em php, e uma div oculta que ao clicar no link em cada registro abre essa div oculta com um mapa. Porém quando adiciono um registro com o link do mapa, só mostra um registro.

Meu código é o seguinte:

jquery:

```
  $(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.caixa .maisinfo a', function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.parent()
            .parent()
                .nextAll( ".mapa:first" ) //Isto vai procurar o mapa a seguir do elemento .caixa
                   .slideToggle();
    });
});
```

html:

```
  <?php do { ?>
    <div class="caixa">
      <div class="maisinfo"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="imagens/local.png" width="15" height="20" /></a></div>
    <table width="510" height="72" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4">
      <tr>
        <td width="15" rowspan="3" align="left" valign="top"><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
        <td height="31" colspan="2"><span class="style5"><?php echo $row_RS_busca['nome']; ?></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="29" height="16" align="left" class="style3"><img src="imagens/tel.png" width="10" height="15" /></td>
        <td width="450" align="left" valign="bottom" class="style6"><?php echo $row_RS_busca['telefone']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="17" align="left" class="style3"><img src="imagens/local.png" width="10" height="17" /></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" class="style6"><?php echo $row_RS_busca['endereco']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
          </div>
    <br/>

    <div class="mapa" style="display:none;"> <?php echo $row_RS_busca['mapa']; ?> </div></div>
      <?php } while ($row_RS_busca = mysql_fetch_assoc($RS_busca)); ?>
```

Comment: acredito que alterar seu loop do/while para while vai resolver o problema

Comment: Sua duvida não tem ligação com css e js, é um problema de php, use as tags relevantes a duvida e não ao sistema. Por favor poste um código que possa ser reproduzido do php+mysql. Pode ser um problema na query.

Comment: Notei que está usando o código que lhe indiquei na outra resposta, por favor se a minha outra resposta (na outra pergunta) lhe resolveu o problema, marque-a como correta no botão "verde" ao lado, se não sabe como fazer isto acesso o tour por favor: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido, era que o campo do mapa na tabela mysql era de tamanho 300 caracteres, e o link tinha mais de 300 caracteres.